# How to programmatically disable security warning in Internet Explorer (8)?

Tags: internet-explorer, security-warning

Need a way to disable PROGRAMMATICALLY the security warning in IE8. 
It's the one which asks 'do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely' while browsing over httpS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is to protect the user against malicious or otherwise deceptive sites.  You can't just make the message go away.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure all links on the page are HTTPS and none are HTTP and it will not show this dialog box.